# s3-dist-cp fails with OutOfMemoryException when I upgrade from EMR 5.7 to EMR 5.8

Tags: amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I have been using s3-dist-cp to move compressed JSON files from S3 to HDFS as part of a bigger job. I started with EMR 5.4 and upgraded through most 5.x, I currently run a 32 machine cluster with EMR 5.7 with no problem.

When I attempted to upgrade to EMR 5.8 the s3-dist-cp job fails as shown below. Has anything changed between 5.7 and 5.8 that would cause this?

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p
kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 11042
kill -9 11042"...
/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/bin/s3-dist-cp: line 55: 11042 Killed                  hadoop jar "$S3_DIST_CP_JAR" -libjars "$LIBJARS" "$@"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be too late, but yes, there was a bug on s3-dist-cp that causes on failures of s3-dist-cp jobs on emr-5.8.0 that would otherwise work on emr-5.7.0. This bug probably causes OOM on S3DistCp  client  because it consumes more memory when Listing of S3 objects before the MapRed job is actually submitted.  it was fixed in 5.9.0.

Comment: Yes,  I ended up opening a support case and they fixed in in the next EMR release.

Comment: @jc mannem - when you say s3distcp list the objects, do you know if these actions are charged by aws? or aws only charges for the emr usage?